# Unable to delete directory, imutable flag is not set, not mounted

Tags: permissions, filesystems, lxc, lxd, snap

So i have this directory that causes a lot of problems when trying to delete lxd via snap. The directory in question is `/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/default/`. If I try to delete it with `sudo rm -fr /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/default/` I get the following error:

```
rm: cannot remove '/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers-snapshots': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/default/images': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/default/custom': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/default/custom-snapshots': Operation not permitted
```

---

#### Checks I have ran:

To find out why I can't delete it I tried to run some checks on one of the folders I'm not permitted to delete (`/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers`)

This is the checks i have ran:

**Immutable flag** with `lsattr -a /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers`:

```
------------------- /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers/.
------------------- /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers/..
```

Ownership with `ls -la /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   0 Mar 15 16:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 116 Mar 15 16:27 ..
```

Checked that it is not mounted with `mount | grep lxd`, which gave no output.

My first goal was just to delete lxd, but now I am really interested in finding out why I can't delete this folder.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to go about debugging this, as I have ran out of ideas. Some useful info:

- I don't have any lxc/lxd binaries because of my idiotic attempts to remove lxd, and now I cant reinstall it, because snap thinks its already installed.
- The storage pool was installed with lxd init, using btrfs

---

#### Update 1

`SELinux` is not enabled. Checked by `$ getenforce` which gave `Disabled`

Comment: Is `SELINUX` enabled?

Comment: @NasirRiley No, I just ran the `getenforce` which gave `Disabled`

Comment: Are there any containers/images up and running? Is the service stopped?

Comment: @NasirRiley Not sure how to check this without the lxd binaries, not sure if its posible to check it without them even. But i disabled all snapd and reboot-ed, then I ran `sudo ps -aux | grep <name>`, with `<name>` as snap, lxd, lxc and none of them yielded any results. Thanks for the help. I should also mention that the containers folder is empty, so I dont think any containers were installed at the end

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is being used somehow and that's why you can't delete it. Does snap refer to snaphot?

Comment: `snap` refers to the `snap package manager`